# How to use Linq to select desired data

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have the following model:

```
public class EventList
{
    Event[] Events {get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
    EventType Type {get; set;}
    Guid Id {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<Accounts>? Accounts { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<MetaData>? Metadata { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<Roles>? Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I would like to get the data that has EventType.Added, and also only want those events that regards  roles with the Id of 42.

I have done this to sort only get them that has the EventType.Added:

```
var addedIdentities = eventList.Events.Where(x => x.EventType == IdentityEventType.AddedIdentity);
```

Now I would like to sort this even further, by only get the data that belongs to events with roleId 42:

```
var identitiesByRoles = addedIdentities.Where(x => x.Roles.Where(y => y.RoleId == 42));
```

This clearly don't work, and I don't really know how to solve this in Linq in a nice way?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var identitiesByRoles = addedIdentities.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(y => y.RoleId == 42));
```

Or, if `x.Roles` could be `null`:

```
var identitiesByRoles = addedIdentities.Where(x => x.Roles?.Any(y => y.RoleId == 42) == true);
```

And combining with the other `.Where`:

```
var addedIdentities = eventList.Events
    .Where(x => x.EventType == IdentityEventType.AddedIdentity)
    .Where(x => x.Roles?.Any(y => y.RoleId == 42) == true);
```

Comment: Possible to do a oneliner here with both roles and eventype?

Comment: @JuggernautDev There you go.